# How to see variable type while debugging C++ in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

While debugging C++ code in Visual Studio Code, is it possible to see type of VARIABLES ?

VARIABLES or WATCH view only show variable name with variable value. Is there an option to show also variable type ?

Comment: You mean static types or dynamic types?

Comment: Did you mean that `double, float etc...` or `lvalue, xvalue, prvalue` ?

Comment: yes, double, float, etc.. when you hover with the mouse you can see the type, but how to change those views to have it immediately for all variables (if possible ? )

Comment: Kind of a hacky workaround, but you can use the debug console repl to evaluate expressions like `this.foo` where foo is some non-existent member variable – you'll get an error message like `class ZZZ has no member foo`

Answer (score 3):

hover over the variable NAME portion of the line. if you hover over the VALUE portion it will just show the expanded value. not intuitive till you realize it

Answer (score 2):

I use GDB from MinGW to compile and debug C codes.

While in debug console, use command `-exec ptype variable_name` to show types of variable.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps this site can help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019

As I see here, the variable types are displayed.

Comment: this answer relates to Microsoft Visual Studio , not to Visual Studio Code.  They are complete separate pieces of software. Don't  ask me why the name are so closed...

Comment: @sandwood Microsoft historically chose the name Visual Studio to benefit of the name of *IBM Visual Age for C++*.